# Django-based Azure Web App getting stuck when development server is run (on Kudu)

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

To migrate an app from Heroku to Azure, I recently created a Django Azure Web App, connected it to my GitHub account and pushed my existing app code onto it via `git push azure master`. After some hiccups, I got all required packages to install correctly too (hiccups being installation of packages which required [pythonwheels](http://pythonwheels.com/)).

I have NOT yet run `syncdb` on the app (the DB's to be hosted on a separate VM; it's postgresql). But I did try to run `env\scripts\python manage.py runserver` to see whether the development server would go up. **It doesn't; Kudu gets stuck (shown below).**
[image]

How can I get it to run? My web.config file is as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="pythonpath" value="%SystemDrive%\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="hostingstart-python.application" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="unconnectedreddit.settings" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

My project is called `unconnectedreddit` and it's placed inside wwwroot. The files `manage.py`, `Procfile` and `web.config` are placed at this level too. Procfile is a Heroku legacy; it contains code regarding what process to run on Heroku, e.g.: `web: newrelic-admin run-program waitress-serve --port=$PORT unconnectedreddit.wsgi:application`

The folder unconnectedreddit (see attached image) contains the `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` files. It also contains a folder called `template`, and a folder called `static`.

The app files are inside the `links` folder (i.e. `models.py`, `views.py`, `forms.py`).

All packages are installed in `env/Lib/site-packages/`.

Can someone explain what my setup lacks and how I can rectify it? Perhaps it's the mis-configured web.config, perhaps I need the Azure equivalent of Heroku's Procfile (though is that really necessary for a development server?), or perhaps it's something else.

I'll share more information if you feel you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to run the development server since it needs to bind to a socket. The only accessible ports are 80 and 443, however, Azure App Service itself is already bound to those. I suggest configuring your app with wfastcgi. See this example for details:
https://github.com/theadriangreen/sample-azure-website-django-app

(Note: this is the same as gallery item for Django)

Comment: We're probably closer to the truth. I tried that, and I got `Error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably be changing my approach

Answer (score 1):

Running a Django app as an Web App should be fine. Documentation suggests setting up a virtualenv for the app, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/#web-app-development---maclinux---command-line

`Web.config` is unnecessary unless you need to use `HttpPlatformHandler`. If you have initiation needs see http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference.

Each Web App is assigned a port number that is bound the `HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT` environment variable. App Service will terminate incoming requests and forward them to the specified port. If Web App for some reason doesn't run the Django app you can explicitly tell `HttpPlatformHandler` how to execute the app, e.g. by writing a batch-file that runs `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%` and have `HttpPlatformHandler` execute the file.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to see the HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT environment variable in `https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env`?

Comment: Not necessarily. They can be specific to a process. It's worth noting that the port is not static and can change between deployments or Web App restarts.

Comment: I ended up getting `CommandError: "0.0.0.0:%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.` True, I didn't create a virtualenv. But I can't make the connection how that would alleviate my problem with the port. Thoughts?

Comment: Is this the result of a batch-file invoked by HttpPlatformHandler? If so, I'd suggest looking into enable delayed expansion.