# How to set up continuous integration on Azure VM (v1)

Tags: git, azure, continuous-integration

Setting up continuous deployment on Azure Web Apps is quite straight forward - one simply connects it to their version control repository (GitHub in my case) through the management portal (settings > publishing > continuous deployment), and that's basically it.

But I don't see a similar option for classic Azure VMs. Can someone guide me how to set up **continuous deployment** (integration) for classic VMs? Or is it not possible and I'll have to accomplish it manually every time (say via logging into the VM and running `git pull origin master`?

Comment: You can still have an Azure extension run a script once it is deployed, you can script any post deploy steps through there.

Comment: Basically doing it manually is the only way (i.e. there's no automation for that on the portal)?

Comment: Its not really a manual approach, you write a script, point the machine to it when it is built and never have to log in to it manually. - Is there a reason you're wanting to use v1?  as you say v2 is much more straight forward.

Comment: Web Apps is much more straight forward, not a V2 virtual machine (I amended that a while ago). And why I can't use Web Apps is because my app is Django/Python, and I can't run a Django development server on Azure Web Apps to test my set up (the required ports are blocked).

Comment: It seems there is a little terminology confusion here! Web apps are basically a fully managed webserver, that hides all of the complexity of the underlying hardware and basically gives you an ftp address to put code (alternatively they can automatically put the code there from github etc) - A virtual machine comes in v1 (classic) and v2 (resource manager) flavours this is basically an unmanaged server. You need to log into it and configure it to do whatever you need. If a webapp can't provide what you need you will need to configure a virtual machine instead, and manually configure it

Comment: Yes indeed, I understand that. Web Apps were thus my first choice, till I ran into the problem with the port (documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005852/django-based-azure-web-app-getting-stuck-when-development-server-is-run-on-kudu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuous deployment for classic VM's is a bit tricky, as @Michael B said, you can use the scripts to run post deployment, or I think you can use something called service hooks.
Service Hook will be able to pull a build from your Git repo the moment you make a push, more details here https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044, hope its easy to setup for you.